# Specifying requireness of a parameter in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have a method in a service contract.
How can I specify  that a parameter  to the method is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no declarative way to do this. You will need to check this yourself inside your service method and throw an appropriate error (SOAP fault for SOAP bindings, HTTP error for REST binding) for this.

The only point where you can enforce a value is on a `[DataContract]` - the `[DataMember]` attribute can have a `IsRequired=true` setting:

```
[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public string employeeName = null;
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public int employeeID = 0;
    ...
}
```